# Can't install atomic ruby atomic gem in rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've been doing quite a bit of research on this issue the last week or so but haven't found a solution that works for me, it's very frustrating. Hopefully somebody can point me in the right direction. Here's the error I recieve

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/Name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
* extconf.rb failed * Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options: --with-opt-dir --without-opt-dir --with-opt-include --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include --with-opt-lib --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib --with-make-prog --without-make-prog --srcdir=. --curdir --ruby=/Users/Name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby --with-atomic_reference-dir --without-atomic_reference-dir --with-atomic_reference-include --without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include --with-atomic_reference-lib --without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/ /Users/Name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first. from /Users/Name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:519:intry_link0' from /Users/Name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:817:in try_run' from extconf.rb:24:in'

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@swi----ense/gems/atomic-1.1.12 for inspection. Results logged to /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@sw-----nse/gems/atomic-1.1.12/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.12), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that gem install atomic -v '1.1.12' succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: What is your environment? I just ran `gem install atomic` on my mac, OS X 10.8, using RVM and Ruby 2.0, with no problem.

Comment: Since you're using RVM, is it up to date? Run `rvm get stable` to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
gem install atomic -V
```

And then:

```
gem install rails -V
```

The -V is for Verbose. You'll see what happen.
It worked for me on a Linux box, when `gem update` didn't.

You also need to have the latest rubygem / bundler.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I didn't have the right version of XCode Developer Tools for OS X Mavericks. Then when I tried to update it, it said it wasn't available from the Software Update server. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907576/xcode-is-not-currently-available-from-the-software-update-server).