# `xcode-select --install` failing

Tags: xcode, terminal, imagemagick, macports

Running OS X 10.9 trying to upload MacPorts following their [guide](http://guide.macports.org/#installing.xcode.mavericks)

```
Jadam$ xcode-select --version
xcode-select version 2333.
```

so I have Xcode on the computer, but when I enter in `xcode-select --install` I get the following return in the terminal:

```
xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools
```

Immediately followed by a, pop-up, update error message:

```
"The xcode-select command requires the command line in 
developer tools. Would you like install the tools now?"
```

with the options "Get Xcode", "not now" & "Install". When I choose install, a "Finding Software" loading bar runs through but then ends with the following message:

```
"can't install the software because it is not currently 
available from the software update server"
```

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907576/xcode-is-not-currently-available-from-the-software-update-server) clearly did not work for me.

Answer (score 15):

[The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19908327/2127896) in the thread you linked is one of the possible solutions. It seems the installer will also display this message if your Command Line Tools are current and there are no updates available.

To check whether this is the case for you, check whether `/usr/lib/tclConfig.sh` exists on your system. Only the Command Line Tools contain this file on Mavericks, so if you have it, you also have the Command Line Tools installed.

Answer (score 6):

I got the first message because I accidentally minimized the window installing the dev tools so might be worth checking that :)

Answer (score 2):

I had to view all open windows on my mac, and look for a dialog window asking for permission to install them.