# Git: Error: Unable to read SDK settings for MacOSX.sdk

Tags: git, terminal, macos-mojave

Error while adding in git after updating to new OS Mojave

**Error**

git: error: unable to read SDK settings for '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk'

**Error faced in:**

- Device: MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2013)
- OS: MacOS Mojave

**Screenshot**
[image: Screen Shot of Terminal]

**Question**

How to solve this error ?

Anyones help will be really appriciated.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

CommandLineTools is outdated. The below should fix it.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: It worked for me. So I'm upvoting. Mojave on MBP 15 2017 using iTerm.

Comment: I wish it could work, but I need to download the Command Line Tools, because the problem Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server. Then I refer to the link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907576/xcode-is-not-currently-available-from-the-software-update-server) found the update. But There isn't  Command Line Tools(macOS 10.14) for Xcode 9.4.1

Comment: worked for me too, should be default for xcode. how often did we already did this in the past and how often will we doing this... thx for the answer/reminder

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the following to resolve:

```
xcode-select --install

sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I had just updated Xcode (using the AppStore) I had to open Xcode and let the installer finish some configuration work before Visual Studio for Mac would successfully compile my Android application again.

I thought this was weird because my solution did not include any projects targeting iOS. The solution contained just a few .NET Core library projects and an Android APK.

I also had to run the 'xcode-select --install' command.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go to Xcode Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools > Select latest Xcode version

[image]