# `npm install` fails on node-gyp rebuild with `gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!`

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, macos-catalina, node-gyp

Every time I try `npm install`. I get the following error. How do I fix it?

```
gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
```

I am on `node -v → v8.8.0` & `npm -v → v6.11.3`

I tried to run it on VSCode terminal and iTerm, but both ended up getting the same error. (both are updated to the latest version). The only new thing I did is updating my macOS to the latest version (Catalina 10.15.3 today).

```
$ npm install          Fri Mar  6 17:22:40 2020

> fsevents@1.2.11 install /Users/synapse/Documents/synapsefi-dev-ui/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/synapse/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:344:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/synapse/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.0/bin/node" "/Users/synapse/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/synapse/Documents/synapsefi-dev-ui/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v8.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN synapsefi-dev-ui@2.0.20 No repository field.
npm WARN The package country-data is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package react-dropzone is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Simply running `sudo xcode-select --reset` worked for me on Catalina.

Comment: Please see https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/macOS_Catalina.md for a step by step guide on resolving this issue.

Comment: Confirming sudo xcode-select --reset worked for me on Catalina 10.15.7.  I no longer get the error when creating a react project with npm; npx create-react-app naboo --template typescript

Answer (score 639, accepted):

Even though you have them installed (my case), but by upgrading to Catalina (10.15.*) you can get this error (my case :) ).

Therefore, simply installing wouldn't help as you will get an error that they are already installed.

Therefore you need to hopefully just **(I) reset** the tool or in worse case **(II) uninstall and install** (requires ***large redownload***) it again (this is based on the @Dane_duPlessis's answer).

```sh
# just for а preview (not necessary)
xcode-select --print-path
# in my case it printed `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

# could be useful if the path is making a problem
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

# only for the (I) resetting case
sudo xcode-select --reset

# only for the (II) uninstalling case - the next line deletes folder returned by the `xcode-select --print-path` command
sudo rm -rf $(xcode-select --print-path)


# only for the (II) uninstalling case - install tools (again) if you don't get a default installation prompt
xcode-select --install
```

**NOTE**:

- You do not need to do it per project, but only once
- There was also discussion that you have to do it on every OSX update, in my case, later updating the OSX system didn't trigger this issue again

Credits to: [gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected macOS Catalina](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/gyp-no-xcode-or-clt-version-detected-macos-catalina-anansewaa-38b536389e8d)

Comment: I just found out that whenever Apple pushes an update, it will always result in this error

Comment: Running `xcode-select --install` opens the install dialogue but then when I agree to terms and click on install it fails with: `Can't install the software because it is currently not available from the Software Update Server`

Comment: This solved the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63990975/5112418

Comment: You can download the developer tools from here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: If you too get the *`Can’t install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server`* error, and if you don't want to install Xcode, as the solution @AHonarmand linked suggests, simply download the command line tools manually from here https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=command%20line%20tools -- that's what fixed this for me. EDIT: (Source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660641)

Comment: Thanks. Every update gets me frustrated. I'd like to dedicate to Apple the same phrase as Linus said to NVidia.

Comment: Thanks I already upvote but today the same answer help me again, I would upvote again if can

Comment: `sudo xcode-select --reset` did the trick for me. thank you

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I have used this answer multiple times!

Answer (score 138):

This worked for me with macOS Catalina Version 10.15.5:

```
$ xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
$ sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
...
$ sudo xcode-select --reset
...
```

The xcode cli tools should now be accessible. No need to re-install anything.

Comment: Confirming this works on Catalina. Much easier than a full reinstall

Comment: This should be the main answer, no need for a lengthy reinstall. Worked on 10.15.7 Catalina

Comment: This worked for me perfectly!! This should be the correct answer.

Comment: Wish I knew about it before deleting my CommandLines directory.

Comment: It doesn't work on macOS Big Sur unfortunately. I get `xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'` even though it's the correct path.

Comment: Why is `xcode-select --print-path` required if the output isn't being used?

Comment: This moment, when you just deleted the app, waiting for the reinstall and scroll through the other solutions... god damnit

Answer (score 60):

I guess, you may have tried multiple solutions so far but if none of those solutions have worked for you yet, don't worry - I got you. :)

**Non-working Solutions:**

1. `xcode-select --install` didn't work for me (macOS Catalina 10.15.7) as it shows up a Software Update dialog box which says `Can't install the software because it is currently not available from the Software Update Server`.
2. I also downloaded and install Xcode Command Line Tools from Apple's download website (https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=for%20Xcode) but the problem re-appeared somehow or may be it didn't solve it in first place and I somehow didn't notice.
3. `sudo xcode-select --reset` also didn't do the trick for me.
4. Someone suggested to install whole XCode. No, thank you.

**Working Solution:**

Here is what worked for me i.e. reinstall Xcode Command Line Tools using Software Update manually.

1. Check if Command Line Tools Update is mentioned in your list of softwares to be updated by using following command: `softwareupdate -l`
2. If Command Line Tools Update is not mentioned in that list, then manually make it part of the list using following command which will create a temporary file: `sudo touch /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress`
3. Verify that the list now has the Command Line Tools mentioned by running `softwareupdate -l` again.
4. Now, press Cmd+Space to initiate Mac's Spotlight Search. Search for `Software Update`. Start the `Software Update`.
5. That will show you following kind of dialog for installing the Command Line Tools. Install away the update and be merry. :)
   [image]
6. Remove the temporary file created in Step 2: `sudo rm /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress`.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. I'm on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7. Thank you!

Comment: This also works for me. Thank you for saving me a lot of reinstall time.

Comment: This is what worked for me. Thank you! My command line tools had the correct install path but updating this way is what did the trick.

Comment: Note you likely don't need sudo to touch a file in /tmp

Answer (score 34):

Try these commands:

```
sudo rm -rf $(xcode-select -print-path)

xcode-select --install
```

If the above **didn't** resolve your issue, you may have a problem with the path Xcode is installed at. Use the following to help if necessary.

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Comment: Simple.  Described here...https://reactgo.com/gyp-xcode-or-clt-version-detected/

Answer (score 20):

I was facing the same issue [image: error message]

I reinstalled the command line tools.

[image: re installing]

You need to find the installation directory.

```
xcode-select --print-path
```

Delete the existing installation:

```
sudo rm -r -f /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Install by running:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: works flawlessly @Akhilesh!

Comment: It's installing now. Says "About 197 hours, 28 minutes remaining"... gotta love that

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Comment: Worked for me on macOS Catalina v10.15.7. It used to work a year ago, maybe before I upgrade to Catalina.

Comment: Just reset worked for me too. I'm using Big Sur 11.2.3.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too on Big Sur (MacOS v11.3)

Answer (score 7):

If your Mac has been upgraded to `macOS Catalina (10.15)`, you need to install the XCode Command Line Tools by running `xcode-select --install`. Alternatively, if you already have the full Xcode installed, you can find them under the menu`Xcode → Open Developer Tool → More Developer Tools`.

Answer (score 6):

This happens most of the time when there is new OS updates happens.
But I found a solutions to tackle this problem. You need to follow the below steps to solve.

Reinstall command-line tools by removing the previously installed version.

step1: First, get the location of the installed command-line tools

```
xcode-select --print-path
```

the result of the above command /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

step2: removed the folder

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

step3 - install again

```
xcode-select --install
```

With the reinstallation of the command line developer tools the gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected error message should disappear when you run any yarn or npm commands from the command line.

Comment: Update on my Answer above

If you have updated your OS to OSX Catalina 10.15.7 then xcode-select --install might not work. You might get an error saying the software is not found on server.

I have found 2 solutions for this

Solution 1: If u can afford to have xcode App from App store which is of 11+ GB then you can fix the error.

Solution 2; You can download the command line tool from official Apple Developer Account  and install it.

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=command%20line%20tools

Answer (score 4):

you will need to install xcode or command line tools

Answer (score 4):

Running `xcode-select --install` attempts an install, but fails with the following error: `Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server.` Here's what worked for me.

```
OS: Catalina 10.15.6
Xcode-select version: 2373
```

NOTE: Before running all this, I already had xcode-select version 2373 installed. But removing and reinstalling fixed the issue.

1. uninstall xcode-select

`sudo rm -rf $(xcode-select -print-path)`

2. Go to the app store, and download XCode.
3. Open XCode. On initial load, it will update/install stuff. let this happen.
4. From Apple Developers, manually download [Command Line Tools for Xcode 12](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
5. Install the CLT for Xcode 12 package.

You should now be good to go.

Answer (score 4):

this happened to me when i installed node-gyp as a dependancy and ran it in a script.

once i installed it globally

```
npm i -g node-gyp
```

it worked! (big sur)

Answer (score 2):

On catalina i did the following:

```
xcode-select --print-path
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

And since install command doesnt work, I had to download it from:
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

From there install:

```
XCode 12
Command Line Tools for XCode 12
```

Post that removed existing node_modules and reinstalled through `npm install`. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when the project required node version `10` but I had `12+`

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly this, my issue is gone now.
First:
`xcode-select --print-path`
it gave path `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

so:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```

it pops up the install window, just install and you are on your way.

Thanks Stackoverflow!

Comment: Duplicate answer.

Answer (score 0):

on catalina had to manually install command line tools for xcode from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: this is better off as a comment rather than an answer because this is a link only answer

Answer (score 0):

On macOS Catalina:

1. Uninstall "Command Line Tools for Xcode" with command `sudo rm -rf $(xcode-select --print-path)`;
2. Download "Command Line Tools for Xcode" at [More Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/), then install it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install the Xcode Command Line Tools at all (like in my case).

You may try to:

1. delete `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules` directory (if it exist)
2. and `npm i` again

it executes with some gyp warnings about No Xcode or CLI version detected, but works fine

Answer (score 0):

I updated to Big Sur and receive this error when on Catalina was all ok. But I upgraded xcode and install in another folder.

To install in that folder where was all ok helped me

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command with sudo to reset your command-line tools.

sudo xcode-select --reset

Answer (score 0):

In my case I deleted package.lock.json and it worked, I already had xCode installed

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything and nothing worked. Personally, even if the problem was gyp, it was Next that bugged. So I downgraded in my node.js version. to install next.js and return to the latest version.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31026046)

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked for me, because I had a corrupt install of XCode, once I uninstalled, npm worked again

Answer (score 0):

```
xcode-select --print-path
```

Above should give: */Library/Developer/CommandLineTools*

```
sudo rm -r -f /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

On Monterey , I **installed Xcode via AppStore** not via the command line.

So Xcode was installed in the path "/Applications/Xcode.app/" ( or "/Applications/Xcodex.x.x.app" )

But `xcode-select --print-path` pointed to "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools"

This command fixed

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/
```

Then

```
npm install
npm rebuild
```

Every works