# I have to uninstall and again install xcode-select for each and every project

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, npm, node-modules

I'm **working with several new projects per month** and I have to uninstall and install xcode-select because there is no other solution to perform npm build because it always says

```
gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
```

This is **time-consuming work** because I have to do this for each and every project I start.
The only solution is to uninstall and install Xcode-select again and again,
I found this solution from these question,

- [npm install fails on node-gyp rebuild with ```gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!```](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60573595/npm-install-fails-on-node-gyp-rebuild-with-gyp-no-xcode-or-clt-version-detec)

  xcode-select --print-path

  sudo rm -r -f /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

  xcode-select --install

But there is **no solution instead of uninstalling and installing xcode-select**,
Anyone can help me with this to find a solution instead of uninstalling and installing xcode-select?

Comment: One-liner: `sudo rm -rf $(xcode-select -print-path) && xcode-select --install`

Comment: I need a solutions without removing xcode-select, Reinstall again and again doesn't seem like a good solution

Comment: It is probably not the problem of Xcode CLI; the problem is from node gyp.