# Why the dualshock driver could not be installed via npm install on mac os?

Tags: node.js, npm

Why the dualshock driver could not be installed via npm install on mac os? The installation instruction:
Install with npm install dualshock --global-style, then include with ds = require('dualshock')

```
~ % npm install dualshock --global-style

> node-hid@0.7.2 install /Users/anahel/node_modules/dualshock/node_modules/node-hid
> prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=14.6.0 runtime=node arch=x64 platform=darwin)
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/14.6.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/anahel/node_modules/dualshock/node_modules/node-hid
gyp ERR! node -v v14.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/anahel/package.json'
npm WARN anahel No description
npm WARN anahel No repository field.
npm WARN anahel No README data
npm WARN anahel No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-hid@0.7.2 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-hid@0.7.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/anahel/.npm/_logs/2020-07-28T15_23_51_377Z-debug.log
```

UPD:

Please, look at at error after I reinstalled XCode-tools: [log.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oh2cwKOYMpVrPoH9WFnLzY6_gZHGbC2C/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install fails on node-gyp rebuild with \`\`\`gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!\`\`\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60573595/npm-install-fails-on-node-gyp-rebuild-with-gyp-no-xcode-or-clt-version-detec)

Comment: @jonrsharpe, ty I'll try it right now

Comment: @jonrsharpe, no it's not helped me. Output changed: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oh2cwKOYMpVrPoH9WFnLzY6_gZHGbC2C/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please don't post off-site links, [edit] the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, if I insert output of npm, the stackoverflow give me "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."