# npm ERR! code 1 npm ERR! Canvas or Python related Issue? MacOS M3 Max Sonoma

Tags: python, node.js, macos, npm, node-gyp

**Reproduce**

Root: `npm install` or 'npm install canvas'
npm install canvas

**Error**

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'mern@1.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '11.12.0', npm: '6.10.3' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.16.0', npm: '9.6.7' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated dgram@1.0.1: npm is holding this package for security reasons. As it's a core Node module, we will not transfer it over to other users. You may safely remove the package from yo
ur dependencies.                                                                                                                                                                                     npm WARN deprecated crypto@1.0.1: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/ma
th-random for details.                                                                                                                                                                               npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the fu
ture                                                                                                                                                                                                 npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/lennybeadle/rpsbet_mern/node_modules/color-thief/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/canvas-postbuild.node
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/backend/Backend.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/backend/ImageBackend.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/backend/PdfBackend.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/backend/SvgBackend.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/bmp/BMPParser.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Backends.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/Users/lennybeadle/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin/node /Users/lennybeadle/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build -
-fallback-to-build --module=/Users/lennybeadle/rpsbet_mern/node_modules/color-thief/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/lennybeadle/rpsbet_mern/node_modules/color-thief/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)                                               npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.11
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.16.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/lennybeadle/rpsbet_mern/node_modules/color-thief/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.5.0/canvas-v2.5.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.5.0/canvas-v2.5.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.5.0 and node@16.16.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.5.0/canvas-v2.5.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.16.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.16.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.6 found at "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/lennybeadle/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/lennybeadle/rpsbet_mern/node_modules/color-thief/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/lennybeadle/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/lennybeadle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.16.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/lennybeadle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.16.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/lennybeadle/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/lennybeadle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.16.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/lennybeadle/rpsbet_mern/node_modules/color-thief/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.16.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! ../src/backend/Backend.cc:111:10: warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'msg' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
npm ERR!   return msg.c_str();
npm ERR!          ^~~
npm ERR! 1 warning generated.
npm ERR! ../src/backend/ImageBackend.cc:68:2: warning: ignoring return value of function declared with 'warn_unused_result' attribute [-Wunused-result]
npm ERR!         target->Set(v8ctx,
npm ERR!         ^~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~
npm ERR! 1 warning generated.
npm ERR! ../src/backend/PdfBackend.cc:47:3: warning: ignoring return value of function declared with 'warn_unused_result' attribute [-Wunused-result]
npm ERR!   target->Set(v8ctx,
npm ERR!   ^~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~
npm ERR! 1 warning generated.
npm ERR! ../src/backend/SvgBackend.cc:49:3: warning: ignoring return value of function declared with 'warn_unused_result' attribute [-Wunused-result]
npm ERR!   target->Set(v8ctx,
npm ERR!   ^~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~
npm ERR! 1 warning generated.
npm ERR! ../src/Backends.cc:18:3: warning: ignoring return value of function declared with 'warn_unused_result' attribute [-Wunused-result]
npm ERR!   target->Set(v8ctx, Nan::New<String>("Backends").ToLocalChecked(), obj);
npm ERR!   ^~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! 1 warning generated.
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/Canvas.cc:21:
npm ERR! ../src/Util.h:17:7: warning: 'SetAccessor' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
npm ERR!         Nan::SetAccessor(
npm ERR!              ^
npm ERR! ../../../../nan/nan.h:2514:1: note: 'SetAccessor' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
npm ERR! NAN_DEPRECATED inline void SetAccessor(
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! ../../../../nan/nan.h:112:40: note: expanded from macro 'NAN_DEPRECATED'
npm ERR! # define NAN_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
npm ERR!                                        ^
npm ERR! ../src/Canvas.cc:327:13: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
npm ERR!   if (opts->Get(propName)->IsString()) {
npm ERR!       ~~~~~~^~~
npm ERR! /Users/lennybeadle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.16.0/include/node/v8.h:4007:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
npm ERR!   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!                                           ^
npm ERR! /Users/lennybeadle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.16.0/include/node/v8.h:4010:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
npm ERR!   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!                                           ^
npm ERR! ../src/Canvas.cc:328:22: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
npm ERR!     auto val = opts->Get(propName);
npm ERR!                ~~~~~~^~~
npm ERR! /Users/lennybeadle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.16.0/include/node/v8.h:4007:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
npm ERR!   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!                                           ^
npm ERR! /Users/lennybeadle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.16.0/include/node/v8.h:4010:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
npm ERR!   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!                                           ^
npm ERR! ../src/Canvas.cc:337:13: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
npm ERR!   if (opts->Get(propName)->IsDate()) {
npm ERR!       ~~~~~~^~~
npm ERR! /Users/lennybeadle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.16.0/include/node/v8.h:4007:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
npm ERR!   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!                                           ^
npm ERR! /Users/lennybeadle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.16.0/include/node/v8.h:4010:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
npm ERR!   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!                                           ^
npm ERR! ../src/Canvas.cc:338:22: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
npm ERR!     auto val = opts->Get(propName).As<Date>();
npm ERR!                ~~~~~~^~~
npm ERR! /Users/lennybeadle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.16.0/include/node/v8.h:4007:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
npm ERR!   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!                                           ^
npm ERR! /Users/lennybeadle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.16.0/include/node/v8.h:4010:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
npm ERR!   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!                                           ^
npm ERR! 1 warning and 4 errors generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/lennybeadle/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:203:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 23.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/lennybeadle/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin/node" "/Users/lennybeadle/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "buil
d" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/lennybeadle/rpsbet_mern/node_modules/color-thief/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/Users/lennybeadle/rpsbet_mern/node_modules/color-thief/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"                                npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/lennybeadle/rpsbet_mern/node_modules/color-thief/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.16.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/Users/lennybeadle/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin/node /Users/lennybeadle/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/n
ode-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/lennybeadle/rpsbet_mern/node_modules/color-thief/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/lennybeadle/rpsbet_mern/node_modules/color-thief/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)                npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/lennybeadle/rpsbet_mern/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 23.1.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/Users/lennybeadle/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin/node" "/Users/lennybeadle/rpsbet_mern/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/lennybeadle/rpsbet_mern/node_modules/color-thief/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.16.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.11
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/lennybeadle/.npm/_logs/2023-12-09T22_29_49_469Z-debug-0.log
```

**What I've tried**

- NVM use 12, 16, 20, 21 (none work)
  Npm 6, 9, 10
- Python 2.7 (downgraded) & 3.6
- `sudo npm install --force` / `--legacy-peer-deps`
- Re-installing Xcode Manually

  `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

  `sudo xcode-select --reset`
  as well as other solutions mentioned here [`npm install` fails on node-gyp rebuild with `gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60573595/npm-install-fails-on-node-gyp-rebuild-with-gyp-no-xcode-or-clt-version-detec)
- Installing the missing tools to convert the source code after not being able to use Git: `brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg`

Comment: What makes you think that this could be a Python-related issue?

Comment: `required: { node: '11.12.0', npm: '6.10.3'`... Both of these are end of life. Are you sure you're installing the right thing?

Comment: Thanks guys, I guessed Python as the mentioned node-gyp, color-thief and canvas all used it.

I solved the problem from another forum I lost the link for, will answer and mark as complete. Thanks anyway.

Solution: Color-thief was using an outdated version of canvas, even though it worked on my other pc, the exact same commit. I just deleted color-thief as already spent days aha.

Answer (score 0):

I guessed Python as the mentioned node-gyp, color-thief and canvas all used it.

I solved the problem from another forum I lost the link for.

**Solution:** Color-thief was using an outdated version of canvas, even though it worked on my other pc, the exact same commit. I just deleted color-thief as already spent days aha.