# Cannot install gcc on Mac for some reason."Cannot install the software because it is not currently available from the software update server"

Tags: c, macos, gcc, installation

I had just factory reset my MacBook, so I had to reinstall gcc. I have typed gcc --version into the terminal but for some reason, "Cannot install the software because it is not currently available from the software update server" shows up.  I have also tried installing on another Mac, but the same message appears. Is it a problem with the server?

I have attached a screenshot of the error message and my terminal, please take a look.

[image: "Cannot install the software because it is not currently available from the software update server"]

Comment: [Take a look here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8211796).  (If you have not done so already, looking in the archives explicitly may be what is needed.)  Or it could be that the server is temporarily down for maintenance or some other problem.

Comment: `gcc` is part of XCode, you need to install that from the App Store.

Comment: Do you want the actual GCC or the XCode clang wrapper for it?

Comment: @tadman just gcc, just need it to for coding c

Comment: @Barmar is there any other way, to download gcc for coding c. Coz Xcode take 11 GB. Thanks

Comment: Just grab the XCode "Command-Line Tools" and you've got the basics. `xcode-select --install` should do it. If that doesn't work then you likely have a networking issue you need to resolve. See: [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode is not currently available from the Software Update server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907576/xcode-is-not-currently-available-from-the-software-update-server)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Xcode is not currently available from the Software Update server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907576/xcode-is-not-currently-available-from-the-software-update-server)

gcc is aliased to clang on MacOS so installing Xcode will just give you clang. You can use [brew](https://brew.sh) to install a gcc tap if you need gcc.

If either is fine then you may need to download Xcode from the App Store or check your network connection. You can also download directly from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode).