# Visual Studio Code Python 3 Command/Install Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

When I've been opening VS Code lately I've been getting this message saying

> The "python3" command requires the command line developer tools. Would you like to install the tools now?

Everytime I click yes and the installer prompts me that it can't be found on the server. Not sure what's going on here. I tried looking at other posts but didn't really see a similar issue. Maybe I missed something.

I'm running the latest version of Python 3 when I check it in the terminal.

On MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H2).

[image: Python3 Message]

Comment: Are your python and pip available? What does the VSCode console output when you enter "python", "pip -v"? In addition, it is recommended that you use the latest version of the python extension and reload VScode.

Comment: Hmmm. When I enter 'python' I get WARNING: Python 2.7 is not recommended... However when I enter in 'python3' I get Python 3.8.6 (v3.8.6:db455296be, Sep 23 2020, 13:31:39). It looks like pip -v isn't working so I guess I don't have that. I'm using .zsh for the shell and iTerm2 as my terminal.

Answer (score 2):

According to your description and feedback, the cause of this problem is that the installation tool `pip` cannot be used. You can use the following methods to solve it:

1. You can reinstall `pip` manually. [Install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).
2. Usually, python comes with `pip`, you can also download python again. [Install Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/).
3. You can also use the `conda` command to install what you need when Anaconda is installed. [Use conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html).

Comment: hey @jillcheng! i've got this exact problem when using visual code with an anaconda virtual environment. Your third point seems to imply that I'd have to write a conda command to install the command line developer tools, but what's the command?

Comment: @armara -When you use the conda environment, is there a prompt box suggesting that you install the relevant "command line developer tools"? 
If not, it is recommended that you reinstall pip or python.

Comment: you mean in VScode right? if so, yes, everytime i start VScode i get the prompt. 

i press "install" when i see the prompt, it loads for a minute or so and then responds with "Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server".

Comment: @armara -According to this prompt, it is recommended that you upgrade xcode(IDE on Mac OS X) to the latest version, and then execute 'xcode-select -install', or download it manually from the developer apple website. refer to: [Xcode is not currently available from the Software Update server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907576/xcode-is-not-currently-available-from-the-software-update-server)