# Why does Homebrew say I don't have the latest CLT, when no update is available?

Tags: xcode, homebrew

Homebrew (`brew doctor`) emits the following warning

```
Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you an update run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install
```

but neither option provides any available update. There's also a link suggested for manual download, but numerous CLT versions are listed there and it's not clear which one, if any, would resolve this message; and installing the latest (non-beta) doesn't do the trick.

Is this an error. Am I missing the latest command line tools and if so where do I get them?

(This is a question about configuring my development environment.)

---

macOS: 10.15.7-x86_64;
CLT: 1103.0.32.62;
Xcode: 12.1

Comment: The message is not a harbinger of any ill event, so why not just ignore it? Or file a bug with the Homebrew folks?

Comment: @matt That’s not really the question.

Comment: My comment is not really an answer! I'm just saying, I've seen this message many times and have cheerfully ignored it with no issues, and so have lots of other people (easy to discover that with a little googling), so maybe it's just a bug in `brew`.

Comment: If the question is "what version of command line tools goes with Xcode 12.1", that's pretty obvious.

Comment: @matt No, that's a different question entirely. The warning says "A newer Command Line Tools release is available" not that a newer (and not yet existing) CLT release goes with the currently installed Xcode.

Comment: I am having this same problem, as of today.   Why would this question not be deemed valuable?!

Comment: lulz, i was going to provide an aswer to this question as i believe i found out the issue, it is related to the brew source and how it evaluates xcode versions, it kindof has to do a guess and check because xcode can be installed in different ways, so this is def a false postive due to the homebrew src,

see

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/444c3858dfc79a51cd48312bf65bccb23525a87f/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/xcode.rb#L185

Comment: @ipatch I'll flag to reopen. That should be allowed as an answer. (Note that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19907576/656912) has over 270 upvotes and an answer with 260 upvotes.)